# Stuck on dell logo after systemctl set-default multiuser.target

Tags: boot, systemd, window-manager

I ran systemctl set-default multiuser.target so that I can use i3 without loading gnome. However, after rebooting, I never get to a terminal where I can login, start my session, etc. I am running 20.04 on a dell xps 15 9500. I tried ctrl + alt + f2 but it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried to boot in recover mode to a root shell prompt with networking. From there you can revert the changes you made that caused the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for the xps 15 9500, to switch to tty2 the keys are ctrl + alt + fn + f2.

Now I can get to a shell at least. Still can't startx properly, but that is another issue I suppose